# Getting notification on changes in Google Talk address book

Tags: notifications, xmpp, real-time-updates, google-talk

Is there a service in Google to receive updates when a GoogleTalk user address book has been updated
(added/removed contact) like Facebook real-time updates service.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

The closest thing I found in GoogleDev was XMPP API for Google App Engine
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview#Handling_Incoming_Calls

It gives updates for changes in the the user messages, subscriptions, and presence 
but not for updates in user address book (roster), as well as it require using google appengine infrastructure.

Thanks,

SW developer.